# Per Cell Number Formatting and Conversion to String for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```py
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Parameter': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'Value': [0.222, 43544433.8383, 5462.2, 6888440902.223]})
```

I would like to parse/format on a per row basis, and convert the values to strings in a pandas dataframe, I.e. turning this:

| Parameter | Value (type = float) |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.222 |
| b | 43544433.8383 |
| c | 5462.2 |
| d | 6888440902.223 |

into this

| Parameter | Value (type = str) |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.22 |
| b | 4.35e+07 |
| c | 5462.20 |
| d | 6.89e+09 |

Where exponential formatting of the cell (before converting to string), occurs for values greater than e.g. 10,000

Answer (score 1):

Just call `'{:.2E}'.format` on each of the items in the column, and use `np.where` to assign them where they're >= 10,000, otherwise just use the original value as a string:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].ge(10000), df['Value'].apply('{:.2E}'.format).str.lower(), df['Value'].astype(str))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Parameter     Value
0         a     0.222
1         b  4.35e+07
2         c    5462.2
3         d  6.89e+09
```